# RDF query only returns one record

Tags: ruby, rdf, json-ld

I am trying to query this [dataset](http://opendatacommunities.org/resources_in_dataset.jsonld?dataset=planning-inspectorate-casework&page=1&per_page=20&type_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fopendatacommunities.org%2Fdef%2Fontology%2Fplanning%2Fpins%2FAppeal)
using Ruby RDF. It should be returning 20 records, instead of 1 record. What is wrong with my query or iteration?

```
require 'rdf'
require 'linkeddata'

include RDF

graph = RDF::Graph.load("http://opendatacommunities.org/resources_in_dataset.jsonld?dataset=planning-inspectorate-casework&page=1&per_page=20&type_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fopendatacommunities.org%2Fdef%2Fontology%2Fplanning%2Fpins%2FAppeal")

query = RDF::Query.new({
  :appeal => {
    RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/Agent") => :Agent,
    RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/CaseRef") => :CaseRef,
    RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/Address1") => :Address1,
    RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/Address2") => :Address2,
    RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/County") => :County,
    RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/Postcode") => :Postcode,
    RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/Town") => :Town
  }
})

count = 0
query.execute(graph) do |appeal|
puts "Record #{count += 1}"
puts appeal[:Agent]
puts appeal[:CaseRef]
puts appeal[:Address1]
puts appeal[:Address2]
puts appeal[:County]
puts appeal[:Postcode]
puts appeal[:Town]
end
```

Comment: This is due to not every appeal having an Agent, Address2, PostalCode and County. Specifying that these are OPTIONAL will sort this out.

Comment: Thanks @HenrietteHarmse, that makes sense. Would you know the required syntax to specify as optional in this instance?

Comment: No sorry, I am not really familiar with Ruby or Ruby RDF and the documentation on Ruby RDF seems to thin.

Comment: @arnoldtm, it seems that RDF::Query supports basic graph patterns (i. e. sets of simple triple patterns) only. In order to execute queries with [`OPTIONAL`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#OptionalMatching), you need full SPARQL implementation, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql/blob/develop/README.md). Additional usage examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47247832/7879193.

Comment: Thanks @StanislavKralin, that was of great help. Really have much to learn about RDF.

Answer (score 3):

gkellogg owner of [RDF Github Repository](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/rdf) said...

> You have three options:
>
> 1. Instead of using a hash to construct the query, use explicit patterns:

```
appeals = RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/")
query = RDF::Query.new do
  pattern [:appeal, appeals/"CaseRef", :CaseRef]
  pattern [:appeal, appeals/"Address1", :Address1]
  pattern [:appeal, appeals/"Town", :Town]
  pattern [:appeal, appeals/"Agent", :Agent], optional: true
  pattern [:appeal, appeals/"Address2", :Address2], optional: true
  pattern [:appeal, appeals/"County", :County], optional: true
  pattern [:appeal, appeals/"Postcode", :Postcode], optional: true
end

query.execute(graph) {|appeal| ...}
```

> 2. Use SPARQL Client:

```
require 'sparql/client'
appeals = RDF::URI("http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/")
sparql = SPARQL::Client.new(graph)
query = sparql.select.where(
  [:appeal, appeals/"CaseRef", :CaseRef],
  [:appeal, appeals/"Address1", :Address1],
  [:appeal, appeals/"Town", :Town]).
  optional([:appeal, appeals/"Agent", :Agent]).
  optional([:appeal, appeals/"Address2", :Address2]).
  optional([:appeal, appeals/"County", :County]).
  optional([:appeal, appeals/"Postcode", :Postcode])

query.each_solution {|appeal| puts appeal.inspect}
```

> Use SPARQL:

```
q = %(
PREFIX appeals: <http://opendatacommunities.org/def/ontology/planning/pins-appeals/>
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?appeal appeals:CaseRef ?CaseRef ;
    appeals:Address1 ?Address1 ;
    appeals:Town ?Town .
  OPTIONAL {?appeal appeals:Agent ?Agent}
  OPTIONAL {?appeal appeals:Address2 ?Address2}
  OPTIONAL {?appeal appeals:County ?County}
  OPTIONAL {?appeal appeals:Postcode ?Postcode}
}
)

SPARQL.execute(q, graph).each_solution {|appeal| puts appeal.inspect}
```

Comment: The correct approach is to query their SPARQL endpoint directly. Do not forget `FROM <http://opendatacommunities.org/graph/planning-inspectorate-casework>`. Full dump (500MB)  in N-Triples is also available.