# Ruby SPARQL Client with Property Path Unary * Operator syntax

Tags: ruby, sparql, rdf

This SPARQL query example works fine:

```
require 'sparql/client'
rdfs_vocabulary = RDF::Vocabulary.new("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#")
sparql_client.select.where(:x, rdfs_vocabulary.subClassOf, :type)
```

Extending it with the **Property Path `*` operator** to get all subclasses, the following syntax works as well:

```
sparql_client.select.where(:x, "<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>*", :type)
```

but is it possible to avoid the full-URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sparql_client.select.where([:x, [RDF::RDFS.subClassOf,"*"], :type])`.

See [query_spec.rb](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client/blob/master/spec/query_spec.rb#L242). Related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client/issues/43).